# Remix Browser and Quorum Local Node

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-deployment, quorum, solidity-0.6.x

When i try to deploy any contract using quorum local node in remix browser with solidity version higher than 0.5.0, the contract gets deployed but any transaction to interact (fetch / update) the contract shows an error.

> **Quorum Node**:
>
> Version: quorum-v2.4.0
>
> **Solidity**:
>
> Solc version: 0.6.1 / 0.5.16

**Contract:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.1;

contract Sample{

    struct Structure{
        uint a;
        string b;
    }

    mapping(string => Structure) public s;

    function add(uint a, string memory b)public {
        s[b] = Structure(a,b);
    }
}
```

Can anybody please tell me how to solve this issue.

Comment: **Gas estimation failed**
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction

Comment: @SamuelDare The same code is working fine with Javascript VM and Injected Web3

Comment: Try chainging the EVM version target, recent version of solc require new opcodes from constantinople/peterburg. Try byzantium for example in the compiler settings.

Comment: Probably related, whats the genesis config?

Comment: `"homesteadBlock": 0,
"byzantiumBlock": 0,
"chainId": 10,
"eip150Block": 0,
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"eip158Block": 0,
"isQuorum": true,
"maxCodeSize": 128,
"txnSizeLimit": 128`

Comment: is it because `"constantinopleBlock": 0,` is missing in genesis?

Comment: @Ismael can you tell me how to change the EVM version.

Comment: @GeethapriyaGH In remix.ethereum.org go to "SOLIDITY COMPILER" tab, then from "EVM Version" select a different version "byzantium" for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as of Quorum v2.4.0, the underlying geth is still v1.8.x. That means you are a bit limited to the hardforks and EVM changes you may use when using remix and other solidity compilers.

First, you need to ensure that you have all of the supported hard-forks enabled in Quorum genesis, a quick reference is our own quourm-examples project: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples/blob/master/examples/7nodes/genesis.json#L20

And then you should stick to the solc 0.5.x until we upgrade to geth 1.9.x. This is in progress and release should be out in a few weeks.